# Controlling ruby version used in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an app using Rails 3.0.6 which I run on two machines. I started with ruby 1.8.7 and recently installed ruby 1.9. I swapped my link in '/usr/bin/ruby' to point to the 1.9 install. When I run 'ruby --version' I get the 1.9. However, in my rails app, when I check 'RUBY_PLATFORM' it shows rails is running with 1.8.7.

How do I tell Rails which ruby environment to use? Strangely, this is not the easiest thing to search for. Probably because I don't know enough about it to form a specific question.

Comment: How did you install ruby 1.8.7 and 1.9? Did you use rvm or something else? First thing I'd check is your PATH. See if it's loading the ruby 1.8.7 path before 1.9.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

https://rvm.io/rvm/install

Install RVM using these instructions, then you can manage and switch between different Ruby versions and gemsets very easily. Using RVM you can have both 1.8.7 and 1.9.x (or any other version) on your system without having to constantly manually change your path and ruby alias.

Older versions of RVM used the `.rvmrc` file to automatically switch the ruby within a directory. Newer versions use the `.ruby-version` file.

To switch between rubies, just type `rvm use 2.0.0` or whatever version it is you want to use. For ongoing projects it's a good idea to add the `.ruby-version` file in the root of the directory that contains the version string you want to use, i.e.

```
2.0.0
```

Comment: showing how to install the program is good, but i think it would be even better if you gave a couple examples on how to switch between versions...

Comment: i'm using rvm myself, but to list a possible alternative: there is also rbenv (https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv)